# Using tikzexternalize with pdflscape results in rotated image

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, pdflscape

When using the `external` TikZ library to externalize an image in a `pdflscape` `landscape` environment, the resulting image is rotated by 90 degrees. This does not happen when including "normal" images. How can I avoid this? Or is there another way to have a single landscape page in a PDF that is also displayed in landscape mode in the viewer?

I want the document to look the same, whether `\tikzexternalize` is active or not, so just wrapping the `tikzpicture` in `\rotatebox{90}` is, unfortunately, not an option.

In my real document, only one page is in landscape mode, so unfortunately I can't just use the `landscape` option of the documentclass. Also, I'm using `memoir` for my actual document, in case that makes a difference for the solution.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{mwe} % For the example image
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize % Without externalization, the orientation is correct
\tikzset{external/force remake}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
  \begin{landscape}
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [scale=5] {A};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Output with `\tikzexternalize` commented out: Everything's fine

[image]

With `\tikzexternalize` uncommented: The TikZ `A` is rotated incorrectly:

[image]

Comment: You could add a `\rotatebox` depending on whether `\tikzexternalize@hasbeencalled` is defined and equals `1`. I was however not successful in patching `tikzpicture` in a way that makes everything work correctly.

Comment: @Caramdir: That's a good idea, but that doesn't work with the `trim left` and `trim right` functionality (another thing I didn't mention, sorry!). `rotatebox` doesn't rotate the `trim` direction, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference between the original `lscape` and `pdflscape` is (I think, I don't know the latter so well:-) that `pdflscape` inserts code get the viewer to keep the page orientation in the viewer, but if your viewer is using heuristics to do this automatically (acrobat by default_ then this may not be needed and the two may conflict.

Comment: Thank you! Using `\usepackage[pdftex]{lscape}` instead of `\usepackage{pdflscape}` works great in my case (including the correct rotation of the content, the display of the landscape page in landscape mode in the viewer, the orientation of externalized images, and the `trim left`/`trim right` functionality of the externalized `tikzpicture`).