# Draw at extreme page on landscape page

Tags: tikz-pgf, landscape, draw

I want to draw this page (without the dots) on a landscape page, I found out how to draw from extreme points of a page but it doesn't work for landscape page.
[image]

My try to draw an horizontal line on top :

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

\draw [thick, cap=round] ([yshift=-5mm] current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-5mm] current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is an old problem (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226678/how-can-i-maintain-the-current-page-nodes-for-portrait-when-temporarily-entering).  The easy solution is to not use landscape and just rotate all the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution takes a normal tikzpicture and centers it in landscape page.  To fill the page, all you have to do is make sure it is `\paperheight` wide and `\paperwidth` high.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
%\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\margin}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\pagestyle{empty}%
\ifodd\value{page}\relax
  \margin=\oddsidemargin
\else
  \margin=\evensidemargin
\fi
\noindent\hspace{\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\linewidth-\paperheight}% left side of page
\rlap{\raisebox{\dimexpr 1in+\margin+\topskip-\height}[0pt][0pt]{%
\parbox[c][\paperwidth][c]{\paperheight}{\centering% center contents
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[red] (0,0) -- (\paperheight,\paperwidth);
  \draw[blue] (\paperheight,0) -- (0,\paperwidth);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

---

To make it easier to use, I created environment LSpage.  The lrbox is used just to put the contents inside `\raisebox` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox{\LSbox}

\newenvironment{LSpage}{\begin{lrbox}{\LSbox}\ignorespaces}% BODY goes here
{\end{lrbox}%
\begin{landscape}%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \ifodd\value{page}\relax
    \dimen0=\oddsidemargin
  \else
    \dimen0=\evensidemargin
  \fi
  \noindent\hspace{\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\linewidth-\paperheight}% left side of page
  \rlap{\raisebox{\dimexpr 1in+\dimen0+\topskip-\height}[0pt][0pt]{%
  \parbox[c][\paperwidth][c]{\paperheight}{\centering\usebox\LSbox}}}
\end{landscape}}

\begin{document}
\begin{LSpage}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[red] (0,0) -- (\paperheight,\paperwidth);
  \draw[blue] (\paperheight,0) -- (0,\paperwidth);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{LSpage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I prefer this solution than the one suggested on the comments, it works perfectly, thank you !