# Tikz picture in a single landscape page within a larger document

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays, landscape, remember

I have several landscape pages in a larger document.

I would like to place a TikZ picture centered a `current page.center` while using the `remember picture` and `overlay` keys for the environment.

But there seems to be some kind of conflict between `TikZ` and the `pdflscape`  package I'm using.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

  \node at (current page.center)
    {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,
                      height=\textheight,
                      keepaspectratio,
                     ]{example-image}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Results in

[image]

I was hoping for something more like

[image]

though the page number would appear differently.

Comment: Tikz has a known problem with landscape, whether using pdflscape or lscape (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226678/how-can-i-maintain-the-current-page-nodes-for-portrait-when-temporarily-entering).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you for the link.  That answers my question.  So perhaps mark this question as a duplicate.